# Confused on the same problem

Tags: real-analysis

I  posted this problem earlier and solutions have been released. I am confused.

Let $a_{n+1}= 1-\frac{1}{2}a_n$ and $a_1= 1$.  Does the sequence converge?  If so, what is the limit?

The answer was to consider the subsequences $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$

then $a_{2(n+1)}=1-\frac{1}{2}a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$

my question is how is $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Probably a typo, maybe they meant $a_2 = 1/2$.

Comment: Ok got it......

Comment: Why is it true if that both $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ converge to the same limit, $a_n$ converges?

Comment: @Jodi Because you can show that the sequence itself converges. Then all subsequences must converge to the same limit. So the limits of the odd and even terms are the same.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life ok sorry I think you are right

Answer (score 1):

As you noted,

$$a_{2n+2}=\textstyle\frac12+\frac14a_{2n},\;\text{ and }\; a_2=\frac12.$$

Few calculations, for instance:

$\begin{array}{lll}
n=1 & \rightarrow & a_4 = \frac12+\frac14a_2 = \frac12(1+\frac14) \\
n=2 & \rightarrow & a_6 = \frac12+\frac14a_4 = \frac12+\frac14\big(\frac12+\frac14\cdot\frac12\big) = \frac12(1+\frac14+\frac1{4^2}) \\
n=3 & \rightarrow & a_8 = \frac12+\frac14a_6 = \frac12+\frac14\big(\frac12+\frac18+\frac1{4^2}\cdot\frac12\big) = \frac12(1+\frac14+\frac1{16}+\frac1{4^3})\\
\ldots &&\\
\end{array}$

suggest that in general we have
\begin{equation}
a_{2n} = \frac12\,\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\,\frac1{4^{k-1}}+\frac1{4^{n-1}}\Big) \qquad(n\geq2).\tag{*}\label{a2n}
\end{equation}
This can easily be proved by induction on $n$:

\begin{align}
a_{2n+2}&= \frac12+\frac14a_{2n} = \frac12+\frac14\cdot\frac12\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{4^{k-1}}+\frac1{4^{n-1}}\Big)=\\[1ex]
&= \frac12\Big(1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{4^k}+\frac1{4^n}\Big)=\\[1ex]
&= \frac12\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{4^{k-1}}+\frac1{4^n}\Big)
\qquad\text{q.e.d}.
\end{align}

From \eqref{a2n} it immediately follows that

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{2n}= \frac12\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{4^{k-1}}+\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac1{4^{n-1}}\Big)=\frac12\Big(\frac1{1-\frac14}+\,0\Big) =\frac23,$$

because the series is a geometrical series with ratio $=\frac14$.

About the subsequence $a_{2n+1}$, from $a_{n+1}=1-\frac12a_n\,$ we immediately deduce

$$ \lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{2n+1}=1-\frac12\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{2n}=1-\frac12\cdot\frac23= \frac23. $$

Consequently, we can conclude (see Note below) that

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=\frac23. $$
$\,$

$\bf \text{Note.}\;\;$ Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence. If the subsequences $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n+1})$ both converge to the same limit $L$, then also the given sequence converge to $L$.

Indeed, given $\epsilon>0$, there exist $\;\nu_1\in\Bbb N\;$ and $\;\nu_2\in\Bbb N\;$ such that

$$ \Big[n\geq \nu_1 \implies |x_{2n}-L|\leq\epsilon\Big] \quad \wedge\quad \Big[n\geq \nu_2 \implies |x_{2n+1}-L|\leq\epsilon\Big], $$

therefore

$$ n\geq\max(\nu_1,\nu_2) \implies \Big[|x_{2n}-L|\leq\epsilon \;\wedge\; |x_{2n+1}-L|\leq\epsilon\Big] $$

and hence the conclusion, since every $\,m\in\Bbb N\,$ is of the form $\,2n\,$ or $\,2n + 1.$
$\,$

You can generalize this to more (but for a finite number of) subsequences.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to comment on the other answer when you don't link to your previous question. $a_{2n}=\frac12$ is false in general, as can be seen by calculating the first view terms:

$$a_1=1; a_2=1-\frac12\times1=\frac12; a_3=1-\frac12\times\frac12=\frac34; a_4=1-\frac12\times\frac34=\frac58.$$

This doesn't show any immediately visible pattern, so it's still unclear if the sequence converges. One method that often works is for a moment to assume that the sequence converges, and see if we can derive anything from that especially what the limit could be. That's a **heuristic** method, it helps you to find a potential limit, in the hopes that this gives you more insight into the problem.

So let's assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$ exists. What can we do with that?

Well, we know that $a_{n+1}=1-\frac12a_n$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, we  have as well $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=a$, so we can write

$$a = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac12a_n).$$

Now, by the usual rules for limits, and remembering that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac12a_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}1 - \frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1-\frac12a.$$

So combining the above stream of equations, we get

$$a=1-\frac12a,$$

which has only one solution: $a=\frac23$.

So to recap: If we assume that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and is equal to $a$, then the only possible case is $a=\frac23$.

How does this help? Well, in order to prove that a sequence converges against a limit, you need to shows that the difference between the elements of the sequence and the limit gets as small as you want (and stays small), when you come to later elements of the sequence.

That means we are interested in the difference $b_n:=a_n-\frac23$. Using the above 4 calculated values $a_1$ to $a_4$, we get

$$b_1=\frac13; b_2=-\frac16; b_3=\frac1{12}; b_4=-\frac1{24}.$$

Now this shows a pattern. Each $b_n$ is half as big as the previous one and has the opposite sign. In other words, from those 4 values it looks like (this is at the moment just a conjecture)

$$b_{n+1}=-\frac12b_n.$$

Let's try to prove it!

We have

$$b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-\frac23=1-\frac12a_n-\frac23=\frac13-\frac12a_n.$$

Now we need to subtitute something for $a_n$ that uses $b_n$, this would be $a_n=\frac23+b_n$:

$$b_{n+1}=\ldots=\frac13-\frac12a_n=\frac13-\frac12(\frac23+b_n)=\frac13-\frac13-\frac12b_n=-\frac12b_n.$$

So our conjecture is actually true!

And now we finally seen that the sequence $(a_n)$ actually converges to $\frac23$, because from the above we get that

$$|a_{n+1}-\frac23|=|b_{n+1}|=\frac12|b_n|=\frac12|a_n-\frac23|.$$

So the (absolute) difference between the elements of the sequence and $\frac23$ gets halfed in every step, so it gets below any positve constant $\epsilon$ at one time and stays below that when going further.

To summarize: If you don't know if a sequence given by a recurrence relation converges and to what value, first calculate a few values to see if you can spot a pattern. If that doesn't work (like in this case), assume the limit exists and substitute it into the recurrence relation.

Often (not always) you will get one or two values that are the only potential limits. Now knowing what your limit (if it exists) looks like, try to rewrite the recurrence relation to be for the difference of your sequence and the (assumed) limit ($b_n$ in our case).

Often this turns the recurrence equation into something simpler (like here) where you need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes and No.  Let me explain.

1. Yes, $a_n$ converges to $\frac {2}{3}$. But
2. No, even subsequence is NOT a constant. $a_{2n}$ ≠ $\frac{1}{2}$ for all n.

Given $a_{n+1}$=1−$\frac{1}{2}a_n$  and $a_{0}$ = 1$

The solution is $a_n = \frac {(-\frac{1} {2})^n+2} {3}$

Relabel the index n so that n' start with $0$.

Keep in mind, since n'=n-1, for even n now n' becomes odd

Set $a_0$ =1 we have for n' = 1, 2, and 3

[image]

It is obvious $a_n'$ is not $\frac {1} {2}$ when n' is odd (or n even).

A counterexample is $a_3'$ = .625 = $\frac{5}{8} ≠\frac {1} {2}$ (or $a_4$ ≠$\frac {1} {2}$)